Why can't rotations in general be associated with vectors?
In my textbook, there's a question:

A vector has both magnitude and direction. Does it mean that anything that has magnitude and direction is necessarily a vector? The rotation of a body can be specified by the direction of the axis of rotation, and the angle of rotation about the axis. Does that make any rotation a vector?

The answer has been given as:

No, rotation in general cannot be associated with vectors.

[Emphasis theirs, not mine]
I'd like some clarification on the statement.

Why can't rotations in general be associated with vectors. Don't all rotations have a torque associated with them?

If not, can't another vector be defined?

What are some other examples of things that have magnitudes and directions, but aren't necessarily vectors?


[I'd also like to mention that I'm a high school student so any declaration of obviousness of the answer in the comments, any higher-than-expected level of explanation, and any mention of a 'repost' with a link to a post where the concepts explained are beyond the expected level should be avoided.]

Without more context, it's hard to answer this question. Maybe it's because rotations about different axes don't add in the right way (the vector arrived at by adding the vectors associated with two rotations doesn't correspond to the vector associated with the combination of the two rotations). Maybe it's because when you add two rotations about the same axis such that the sum of the angles is greater than $2\pi$, you get a rotation of less than  $2\pi$. Specifying a vector as a magnitude and direction just isn't enough. You have to consider the algebra, too. Is there more info you add?

I am not sure if if this what you are asking but while we usually associate an axis with a rotation, the axis pointing in one of two directions, and that association is a kind of a vector but it is better to think of a rotation as being associated with a plane and in that plane the sense being either left or right handed turn. In 3D one can almost get away with the "axial vector" thinking: it is a vectorlike creature except against reflections but it does not generalize to higher dimensions. The planar circulation view is a bit more difficult and can also be viewed as a pair of vectors.

Which textbook? Which page?

Related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htYh-Tq7ZBI

A vector can be a useful representation of a simple rotation about an axis. But rotations don't transform or "add" (compose) like vectors. Vector additions commute, but the result of rotations depends on the order you perform them. Do the experiment. Take a box, rotate 90 degrees about X, and the 90 degrees about Y. Then, from the same starting orientation, rotate 90 degrees about Y and 90 degrees about X. Does the box wind up in the same orientation for both procedures?

Transformation and the sum of vectors are two different concepts. I would not mix them. The sum (composition) does not allow finite rotations to be vectors.

So you can encode a rotation using an axis and an angle but they are not vectors in the mathematical sense, as they do not follow the rules of vector algebra.
You cannot add two vectors and the result is a rotation. Also, you cannot use regular linear operators to change the orientation of the rotation. It all boils down to the fact that you cannot multiply vectors which would be an operation to use that can sequence different rotations together.
The closest you can get is with unit quaternions which encode the axis of rotation and the angle using the sine and cosine of the half angle. It turns out, you can multiply quaternions together and a sequence of rotation does indeed result in an rotation always.

A vector is usually described as something that has both magnitude and direction. This is a limited definition. A vector, more generally, is an element of a vector space. To qualify for this it is only necessary the vector space has a number of operations that apply to any object in that space. These are the axioms that define a vector space.
For example, addition (however it may be defined for that space) of two elements produces an element that is also in that vector space. (The vector space is closed under addition.) This addition is both associative (A+B)+C = A+(B+C) and commutative A+B = B+A.
Under this definition some strange things are actually vectors, for example the infinite sequence of real numbers, and more oddly, real-valued functions.  This is what linear algebra is all about.
Rotations do not follow the axioms required of a vector. As has been pointed out (A+B) does not necessarily equal (B+A) for rotations. This is the reason rotations are not vectors.

General rotations are composed by rotations in 2-dimensional planes. The model is
$$x' = x \cos \phi - y \sin \phi, y' = y \cos \phi + x \sin \phi$$
in higher dimensions, leaving all other directions unaffected.
Two such rotations in different planes with no two directions in common  can be combined making up more general rotations.
If the two planes have a common direction, the two rotations cannot be done independently, one has to apply them in a given order
$$x' = x \cos \phi - y \sin \phi,\quad  y' = y \cos \phi + x \sin \phi, \quad   x'' = x' \cos \theta - z \sin \theta \quad  z' = z \cos \theta + x' \sin \theta$$
This is a different composition with the reverse order
$$x' = x \cos \theta - z \sin \theta,\quad  z' = z \cos \theta + x \sin \theta , \quad 
  x'' = x' \cos \phi - y \sin \phi, \quad  y' = x' \cos \theta + x' \sin \theta$$
In $\mathbb R^3$ Euler's theorem states that the combined rotations with any common directions of planes yield another rotation in a third independent plane.
For algebraic simplicity, the rotions are represented by their $n\times n$ coefficent matrices in an orthogonal coordinate system. Then composition of rotations is matrix multiplication, and the rotation matrices form the orthogonal group $SO(n)$.
In the real orthogonal group $SO(3)$ one has the possibility of representing a rotation  by its invariant plane and an angle, or by the invariant 1-d subspace, the axis, and the same angle.
In higher dimensions, this priciple to represent a rotation matrix by invariant subspaces, is much more complicated. Especially, the duality between planes and axes does not exist. The dual invariant subspace of a 2-plane is a $n-2$-dimensional space.
Instead the characterization is performed by a tree of invariant subgroups, which can be done by differential geometry, making all angles infinitesimal and classifying the resulting Lie-algebra,  setting all squares of differential angles used in 2-planes to zero.
So it came as a surprise, that any rotation in  dimension  $2n$ can be represented by series of double reflections at 2n hyperplanes. 'Double' in order  to preserve orientation, because a single reflection at a hyperplane changes the sign of direction perpendicular to it.
Odd dimensions $2n+1$, by the basics, can always be considered as a subspace of a $2n+2$ even dimensional space with one dimension fixed.
The mathematical proof was only possible to be found after the invention of the spin 1/2 representation of the rotation groups of any dimension, that was the hot topic in physics and in pure mathematics in the 1930ties.
A good impression of the rotation group $SO(4)$ for physicists is the Lorentz group with imaginary time with two noncommuting $SO(3)$ subgroups, the images of the real subgroup $SO(3)$ and the group of Lorentz boosts $SO(3,1)$.

Very interesting question. Mathematically vector is just an element from a vector space. Vector space does not necessarily have to be Euclidean spatial space,- it can be ANY parameter space. Let's denote rotation column vector as :
$$\tag 1 \boldsymbol \phi = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\ \sigma \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are angles in $XY, XZ, YZ$ planes by which we should rotate $x$ axis to find the rotation axis. Last parameter $\sigma$ means rotation angle around this found rotation axis.
It can be proved that vector addition $\boldsymbol \phi_1 + \boldsymbol \phi_2$ commutes, because commutes pair-wise component addition, $\alpha_1+\alpha_2 = \alpha_2+\alpha_1$ and etc.
I believe that the rest properties of such vector space defined in (1) could also be proven. So I bet $\phi$ is pretty much vector which represents body rotation.

A vector is defined by the rules for transforming its components following a rotation of the coordinate system. They change like the components of a segment $AB$.
For the sum of two vectors, the definition is immediate: we sum the components. This sum is obviously commutative and the parallelogram rule is an immediate consequence of the fact that the sum of the components of two vectors obviously transforms like a vector.
In this framework, it seems possible to define a vector for a finite rotation. The problem with this vector is that the sum of two rotation vectors has no simple physical interpretation. In particular, the sum of two rotation vectors (defined as above) does not correspond to the composition of the two rotations. So this rotation vector would have no use.
On the other hand, for infinitesimal rotations (and therefore angular velocities) the addition rule defined above corresponds to the successive application of two infinitesimal rotations.
Note that we encounter definition problems even in the simplest cases, such as the velocity vector. We know that it is a vector and we can sum two velocity vectors according to the parallelogram rule. But what does this sum physically mean? It seems to me that we never sum two velocity vectors  for the same particle. In practice, we use the composition of velocities in a change of frame of reference and it is only valid in non-relativistic physics. Which does not prevent velocity from being a vector in a relativistic framework.
There may be a difference between the mathematical definition of the sum and the associated physical definition.
Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.
